# Type of q"null" is Literal, so invalid for return type Expr[X]

Tags: scala, scala-macros

I have a function

```
def grammar(block: => Any): Grammar = macro grammarImpl
```

with macro implementation

```
def grammarImpl(c: Context)(block: c.Tree): c.Expr[Grammar] =
{
  q"null"
}
```

But I get an error, type mismatch;  found   : c.universe.Literal  required: c.Expr[Grammar]     (which expands to)  c.universe.Expr[Grammar]

Replacing q"null" with c.literalNull however compiles fine, am I using the wrong quasiquote to get the Null literal?

(Scala 2.11.6)

Side question: I am using block: c.Tree, when really I want to use c.Expr[=> Any]. Is it possible to specify the c.Expr[=> Any] type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to do

```
def grammarImpl(c: Context)(block: c.Tree): c.Expr[Grammar] =
  c.Expr[Grammar] {
    q"null"
  }
```

but this is deprecated since scala 2.11 (read point 9 below).

Just change the return type to `c.Tree` and be done with:

```
def grammarImpl(c: Context)(block: c.Tree): c.Tree = q"null"
```

This is a change introduced in scala 2.11 and you can read about it [here](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/changelog211.html):

> 8) Relaxed requirements for signatures of macro implementations. With the advent of quasiquotes, reify is quickly growing out of favor as being too clunky and inflexible. To recognize that we now allow both arguments and return types of macro implementations to be of type `c.Tree` rather than c.Expr[Something]. There’s no longer a need to write huge type signatures and then spend time and lines of code trying to align your macro implementations with those types. Just take trees in and return trees back - the boilerplate is gone.
>
> 9) Inference of macro def return types is being phased out. Given the new scheme of things, where macro implementations can return `c.Tree` instead of `c.Expr[Something]`, it’s no longer possible to robustly infer return types of macro defs from return types of macro impls (if a macro impl returns `c.Tree`, what’s going to be the type of that tree then?). Therefore, we’re phasing out this language mechanism. Macro impls that return `c.Expr[T]` can still be used to infer return types of their macro defs, but that will produce a deprecation warning, whereas trying to use macro impls that return `c.Tree` to infer the return type of a macro def will lead to a compilation error.